# Convert Sample Request XML from wsdl to Java

Tags: java, xml, soap, wsdl, wsimport

Here is a sample wsdl: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl and here is a sample Request generated in SOAPUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Add>
         <tem:intA>?</tem:intA>
         <tem:intB>?</tem:intB>
      </tem:Add>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I know there are tools out there like SOAPUI and others that can automatically generate sample XML calls from a wsdl. But is there a way to generate sample request in JAVA after having imported a wsdl client using wsimport?

Answer (score 0):

SOAPUI does not generate a full xml instance. It helps you as much as possible by providing the xml structure. But you must still fill in the data yourself. E.g. in your example the '?'. According to the element name I assume it should be an integer.

Neither Java is able to produce such example xml's. At least I am not aware of such a tool. But XJC is able to produce java classes based on the wsdl. Look out for "XJC" and you will find plenty of resources how to integrate XJC in your build script.